# Prediction for quantile regression using grf package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, quantile-regression

I am training a quantile forest regression using the grf package in R
https://grf-labs.github.io/grf/REFERENCE.html#prediction

My dataset has 12 million records and i am using a 192gb 48 core cluster. The model trains pretty fast ( 3 mins for 50 trees), but the issue is always when using predict.

`predict(q.forest, X.distinct)`

The process is extremely slow and even when I predict a handful of values, it takes a long time to run.

Is there anyway to speed this process up or does it work differently